# So my output is supposed to look like the following

Tags: python

you enter a number and along with the countdown there is a design the one on here is supposed to be a "H"...it doesn't matter if the design is a letter or  picture but with the following recursion code I'm trying to figure out how to add this design alongside the recursion numbers. The below code is only for the recursion code.

```
10        |     |
9         |     |
8         |     |
7         |     |
6         |-----|
5         |     |
4         |     |
3         |     | 
2         |     |
1
takeoff!
```

Current attempt:

```
def countdown(n):
while n >= 0:
    if n == 0:
        print ("takeoff!")
    else:
        print (n)
    n -= 1
```

Comment: Is this an animation where the bar moves down or is it just the one picture shown?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at doing this, or did you stop at the numerical printout?

Comment: its where the the picture gets longer if you input a greater number and shorter if you input a small number. @jeffcarey

Comment: the numerical printout is easy but its getting the right output thats hard so i posted a clean code which worked. my other attempts at printing out a picture with the numerical countdown sometimes had errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use formatting to keep the numbers and picture lined up regardless of the number of digits. Then, just handle the cases that can come up for each number.

```
def countdown(n):
    i = n

    regular = "|     |"
    special = "|-----|"
    while i >= 0:
        if i == 0:
           print "takeoff!"
        elif i == n / 2 + 1:
           print ("{:3} {}").format(i, special) 
        else:
           print ("{:3} {}").format(i, regular)
        i -= 1
```